# Behaviour of previous evolution change

Tags: playframework

**Context**: I have a PlayFramework 2.5 backend with MySQL db running evolutions. I'm currently on evolution #23 running on production.
However, with a fresh install in production one of the previous evolutions #19 gave an error, which made me change the evolution #19 to be abble to run all the evolutions on dev. *The major change* was removing a foreign key.

Assuming I have

> db.autoApply = true
>
> db.autoApplyDowns = true

Thinking I should change autoApplyDowns to false, also not sure how it will influence.

**Question**: What will happen if I save changes on production? Will it ignore #19 since it already applied it?

Answer (score 0):

`autoApplyDowns` only affects running in Production mode and determines whether to apply down evolutions automatically. I would encourage you to set this to `false`.

`autoApply`- cause ups and downs to be automatically applied in Dev, but only ups to be applied in Prod.

The default for both of these settings is `false` and personally I prefer it that way since if there is anything out of sync between the scripts and the state of the DB schema then Play will report the problem so you can manually fix them - it reports these issues when the app starts up (in Prod) or on first request (in Dev).

Safest option would be to change both to `false`, trash your dev DB, and apply all evolutions from scratch as a sanity check on any issues in Dev. This would be safe for Prod since it means only Ups will be applied next time you deploy an evolution change. If you have any issues at that point Play will report the problem before changing the DB schema - you will then have the chance to run some SQL manually on your production DB to get back in sync or back out the release while you think about the problem.

Comment: an "evolution change" means, when I add a new evolution file, or does that also mean it will try to fix an evolution that was already performed but needed to be changed?